# Inline array slicing

Tags: ruby, arrays, range, method-chaining, slice

Hia! I was wondering about an interesting thing recently. Say I have this snippet:

```
params['path'].split('/').delete_at(-1).each do |dir|
   # some work
```

where

```
params['path'] = 'lorem/ipsum/dir/file.ext' #for instance
```

What I actually want to do is to iterate over all members of the ad hoc array except the last one. The snippet obviously doesn't work, because `delete_at` returns the deleted element.

Is there any way to slice array with "inline" syntax? Or am I terribly missing something? Do you know some other tricks to make similar method chaining easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Array#[]` with a range:

```
params['path'].split('/')[0..-2].each
```

Comment: Oh, I see... Since solution similar to the one proposed by arnaud576875 didn't work, I didn't bother to think more about regular slicing. Shame on me :(

Comment: well, that's exactly the same has mine (and mine works too), except that this one uses 0..-2 (end inclusive) instead of 0...-1 (end exclusive).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Array[range]` syntax:

```
params['path'].split('/')[0...-1].each do |dir|
    # ...
```

`0...-1` means from index `0` to index `1` from the end exclusive.

This is the same as `.slice(0...-1)`.

See the docs **[here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000218)**

Try it here: http://codepad.org/HyZ2GHxo

---

You may want to use File.dirname instead:

```
File.dirname(params['path']).split('/').each ...
```

Comment: That's what came to my mind first. But you can see for your self it doesn't work :P

Comment: notice the 3 `...` in the range; it means that the upper bound is exclusive.